# Is there a React lifecycle method to do something only when component receive props the first time?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm new to React so thank you for your patience in advance. Also using Redux.

I have a list of content pulled from the API, I display the text and a hidden text box and on a state change associated that alternates the visibility of the two. Essentially user can click on the text and edit the text, achieved by inverting the boolean and swapping the display. They can then save it and PUT to server etc.

Since my list length varies, I must initialize a number of `state.isVisible[n]`. equivalent to the number of content being displayed each time. This number must be counted, after the props come in. I am using Redux so the content is retrieved, stored, then given to props. It's done as the following:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isVisibleObj: {}
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    const { isVisibleObj } = this.state

    // set visibility of text box
    let obj = {}
    Object.keys(this.props.questions).forEach(key => obj[key] = false)
    this.setState({isVisibleObj: obj})

  }
```

My initial implementation was that in `componentWillReceiveProps` I do all the `setState()` to initialize the `isVisible` properties to a boolean.

The challenge I am having with this implementation is that, if a user open up multiple items for edit, and if she saves one of them, the `PUT` request on success would send back the edited content, now updating the store and props. This will trigger `componentWillReceiveProps` and reset all the visibilities, effectively closing all the other edits that are open.

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make two components

List (NamesList.react)

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import NameForm from './NameForm.react';
import Faker from 'Faker'

export default class NamesList extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }

  addItem(){
    var randomName = Faker.name.findName();
    this.props.addName(randomName);
  }

  render() {
    let forms = this.props.names.map((name,i) => {
      return <NameForm updateName={this.props.updateName} index={i} key={i} name={name} />
    });
    return (<div>
      <div>{forms}</div>
      <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
    </div>);
  }
}

NamesList.propTypes = {
  names: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired
};
```

Form  (NameForm.react)

```
   import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateName =  this.updateName.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showTextBox:false
    }
  }

updateName(){
  this.setState({showTextBox:false});
  this.props.updateName(this.props.index,this.refs.name.value);
}

  render() {

    if(this.state.showTextBox){
      return (<div>
            <input ref="name" defaultValue={this.props.name} />
            <button onClick={this.updateName}>Save</button>
        </div>);
    }

    return (<div onClick={() => {this.setState({showTextBox: !this.state.showTextBox})}}>
      {this.props.name}
    </div>);
  }
}

NameForm.propTypes = {
  name:PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Invoke (App.js)

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NamesList from './NamesList.react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.addName = this.addName.bind(this);
    this.updateName = this.updateName.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      names:['Praveen','Vartika']
    }
  }

  addName(name){
    let names = this.state.names.concat(name);
    this.setState({
      names: names
    });
  }

  updateName(index,newName){
    let names = this.state.names.map((name,i) => {
      if(i==index){
        return newName
      }
      return name;
    });
    this.setState({names:names});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <NamesList names={this.state.names} updateName={this.updateName} addName={this.addName} />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

Now if your store changes after user saves something. React wont re-render Child component that didn't change